# Does the body move with constant velocity or accelerate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics

If I take the case in which a body has a constant force applied of 5N and friction Present is 3N.

Does the body accelerate in this case ? Or move with uniform velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton's law has net force equals mass times acceleration. In your case

$$ 5 - 3 = m a $$

so what do you think happens? $a=0$ or $a \neq 0$?

Comment: a is not equal to 0

Comment: It will move backwards.If it has friction = 7N

Comment: Can’t it move forward at all

Comment: If it is a human walking with these conditions.

Comment: Human walking is not the same as a block sliding with friction. If you have a specific question, then ask it, but not in the comments.

Comment: Friction always opposes the relative motion, and so it will never add energy to the system.